# Download Fuchsia source -- Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages

Tags: installation, fuchsia

Per [Get Fuchsia source code](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/source_code):

```
~$ echo $PATH
/media/cwh/32GB/swdev/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
~$ cd /media/cwh/32GB/swdev/
/media/cwh/32GB/swdev$ curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/scripts/bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash
cipd bootstrapped to path:"/media/cwh/32GB/swdev/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin/cipd"
Please add /media/cwh/32GB/swdev/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin to your PATH
[22:15:04.404] Updating all projects
PROGRESS: Fetching CIPD packages
[22:38:10.385] Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages
[23:01:03.457] Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages
ERROR: context deadline exceeded
```

I do not see any "fatal errors" preceding the Jiri hooks message.

What is the 'Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jiri help update` indicates there are two default timeouts:

```
-fetch-packages-timeout=30
-hook-timeout=5
```

Invoke `jiri` directly with increased timeouts then repeat original command.

```
cd fuchsia; jiri update -fetch-packages-timeout=90 -hook-timeout=60; cd ..
curl -s "https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/master/scripts bootstrap?format=TEXT" | base64 --decode | bash
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was the cipd that failed to fetch some prebuilt artifacts. Just login by running

```
cipd auth-login
```

and then run the fuchsia bootstrap script again.