# Jiri hooks are not run due to fatal errors when updating projects or packages - Fuchsia Source code download

Tags: installation, hook, fuchsia

I am trying to install Fuchsia Source code but it is giving me error while fetching CIPD packages.

[image]

I tried the solution in this stackoverflow post but i received the error. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484262/download-fuchsia-source-jiri-hooks-are-not-run-due-to-fatal-errors-when-updat)

I am just getting started with this and don't know a lot about it. I will be grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend re-running jiri update, it will eventually complete. At present the prebuilts fetched from CIPD are large and can take a long time in certain regions, or with slower internet connections. The downloads are performed incrementally, and so restarting the process should make forward progress and eventually complete. I don't remember offhand the flag, but there is also a flag you can pass to jiri to explicitly increase the timeout.